# What are the touch-pad things that the guitarist and bassist of Muse use?

Tags: instruments, electronics

In concert video footage of Muse, I've seen both the guitarist and bassist use touch-pad devices integrated with their instruments.

What are these devices, and what are they designed to do?

Comment: He also has at least one guitar with ZVex Fuzz Factory built-in, as heard in "Plug-in Baby".

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are x-y MIDI controllers more commonly referred to as [Kaoss Pads](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaoss_Pad).

If you are familiar with a modulation wheel on a MIDI keyboard, you know you can assign that wheel to control any number of aspects of the instrument, from pitch bend, to volume, to vibrato, an LFO, or perhaps a filter. The x-y pad gives you two of those on a plane, with which you can control anything that's MIDI controllable (even lights if you've got the right setup).

Comment: Matt's guitars are made by Hugh Manson- http://www.mansonguitars.co.uk and quite a few have two-  or one-dimensional midi controllers.

Comment: A Kaoss Pad is a type of x-y midi controller (that's used by Muse). Other x-y midi controllers aren't called Kaoss Pads. Kaoss pad also has onboard effects and isn't just a midi controller.